# Split Sum of Value in Pivot Table using Multiple Tabs

Tags: pivot-table

I have a Pivot table using multiple tabs. I would like to use the Top 3 Filter function, showing the top 3 "Items" by "Clicks", and not by the "Sum of Value" that use to calculate both columns, and showing the Top 3 considering the sum of "Clicks" and "Impressions".

Sum of Value        Column labels

Row Labels    Clicks Impressions

**"d"** 14 20

**"e"** 4 10

**"a"** 4 10

**"c"** 4 6

**"b"** 2 4

When I create the Pivot table using the same data, but across only one tab, under Values I have both, "Clicks" and "Impressions", and also when filtering by Top 3 I'm able to choose which one, "Items" by "Clicks", instead of "Items" by "Impressions".

Thanks a lot!